# highlight word by start and end matches using angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a collection of array which is having datas like

```
[0]: username {kavya} secret {password}
[1]: lorem ipsem text data value
[2]: lorem {{lrm}} datas {{pp}}

I am using foreach to show this data in frontend with 

      <div *ngFor="let data of output;let i=index">
          <div *ngIf="data.includes('{') || data.includes('{{');else isNotEdited;" >
            <div class="variable-textarea" contenteditable="false" >
            <span>
              {{data | slice:' ' }}  
            </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ng-template #isNotEdited>
              <ngx-md>{{data}}</ngx-md>
          </ng-template>

          </div>
```

Here I achieved like 0,2 row of div will be editable and in case of 1st array is non-editable.
But I want to do like specific matches which word starts with { or {{ and that particular word needs to be highlight and editable.

Is there any option to do in this way
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add a StackBlitz for the code so that it can be better understood.

Comment: Here I have created working example, where I need to do instead of making entire element editable I need to make editable only word which matches { or {{ in string. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk2vpr

Answer (score 1):

You could split the data into words:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of arr">
    <span *ngFor="let word of data.split(' ')">
        <span *ngIf="word.indexOf('{') > -1;else isNotEdited;">
            <span class="variable-textarea-2" contenteditable="true">
        {{word | slice:' ' }}  
            </span>
        </span>
        <ng-template #isNotEdited>
            <span class="variable-text-2" contenteditable="false">
                {{word}}
            </span>
        </ng-template>
    </span>
</div>
```

Check this Stackblitz example I made based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pkg6i9

Comment: Thanks alot its working fine , small thing has to do with this element which has { row will be in different color and other one in different color like I showed in top of you example., because as per new change its like span so if i give any style its taking for word not for full string or element

Answer (score 1):

this is a performance nightmare, you don't want to be running this many functions in template, and your format isn't helping you. map your data ahead of time into a friendlier view model:

```
this.mappedOutput = this.output.map(data => {
  const editable = data.includes('{'); // checking for doubles is redundant
  return {
    editable,
    data: !editable 
            ? data 
            : data.split(' ')
                  .map(word => ({
                    word, 
                    editable: word.trim().startsWith('{') && word.trim().endsWith('}')
                  })) 
  };
})
```

run this whenever your output changes, then use it in template:

```
  <div *ngFor="let data of mappedOutput;let i=index">
      <div *ngIf="data.editable;else isNotEdited;" >
        <div class="variable-text">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let word of data.data">
            <div *ngIf="word.editable; else wordTmp" class="variable-textarea inline" contenteditable="true" >
              <span>{{word.word}}</span>
            </div>
            <ng-template #wordTmp>
              {{word.word}}
            </ng-template>
          </ng-container>
        </div> 
      </div>
      <ng-template #isNotEdited>
          <ngx-md>{{data.data}}</ngx-md>
      </ng-template>
  </div>
```

and adjust the styles by adding this to your css:

```
.variable-textarea.inline {
  display: inline-block;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 0;
}
```

here's an edited blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arayve?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I am getting this ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined. I am checking this issue

Comment: just check the variable names. they're different in your question and your blitz

Comment: Yeah I changed everything problem is mapping taken place before api returns value im checking that

Comment: yea you gotta do it whenever you get the data, like whenever you normally do that assignment. Or if you're using async pipe, just add it in a map operator

Comment: Is it possible to add condition like word starts and end { } instead of includes { in map?

Comment: say for example somewords are like {{ interface   }} so in this case initial {{ its taking as one word and box shown for that particular {{ so inorder to overcome this issue need to change condition little bit like start and end either by { and } or {{ and }}

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk2vpr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts for reference

Comment: Yes that wouldn’t be very hard at all since you’re doing it in code instead of in template. Just change the conditional after you split the words out